# Custom AngularJS directive, updating the data with $compile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a test directive that just shows some markup on the web page. For some reason, when I try to update the markup using AngularJS's `angular.element()` function, it only shows a visual representation of the object. Much like viewing a JavaScript object from the browser.

```
[[object HTMLInputElement], [object HTMLSpanElement], [object HTMLBRElement]]
```

This is my template page where I am just spitting out the directive, it's too simple.

```
<div my-sample></div>
```

My directive looks like this,

```
eventsApp.directive('mySample', function ($compile) {
    var markup = '<input type="text" ng-model="sampleData" /> {{ sampleData }} <br />';
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, atts, controller) {
            angular.element(element).html($compile(markup)(scope));
        }
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the code seems correct [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3mh45x5/)

Comment: Hence my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$compile` returns DOM elements, not HTML. Try just `element.empty().append($compile(markup)(scope))` instead of using the `.html()` function.